# SPARQL "any" relationship filter

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, wikidata

I want to retrieve entities with any relation to some other entity. Consider following query:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q28598684. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
# Helps get the label in your language, if not, then en language
}
```

Here, I would like to have 'wdt:P31' to be any relationship and I want to return this relationship as well. Is that possible?

Comment: I found that simply putting ?prop instead of wdt:P31 does the work. I'm not sure though

Comment: That will return any subject and object with the predicate specified. So I think that is what you want.

Comment: yes, that is the whole concept of SPARQL, replace the property `wdt:P31` with a variable in the **triple pattern** to make the whole pattern more generic and match more in the RDF graph. Indeed, that would only give you entities as incoming edges, there might be outgoing edges as well, i.e. sometimes those relations might be relevant as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments by the author of the question: you can simply use a variable in the place of the relationship to get the relationship.

```
select ?item ?property ?itemLabel ?propertyLabel {
  ?item ?property wd:Q28598684. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
}
```